# Why photos are not loading?

Tags: flask

I am using flask, but i have problem with image uploading.

My .html file

```
<form class="d-flex align-items-center flex-column" action="{{ url_for('core.index') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label class="m-4 input-wrapper-file">
        <input class="input-file" type="file"/>
    </label>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row w-50">
        <button id="button-reset" class="btn btn-outline-danger mx-2 flex-grow-1" type="button">Reset</button>
        <button id="button-submit" class="btn btn-outline-success mx-2 flex-grow-1" type="submit" disabled>Solve</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My .py file

```
@core_bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('pages/index.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files
        print(file)
        return "Hello world"
```

Request files are empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `name` attribute in your `input` tag.
If you change your input tag to

```
<input class="input-file" type="file" name="file"/>
```

Flask recognizes the file and can access it with

```
file = request.files['file']
```